# Tkinter - Data Storing and Manipulating With Comboboxes

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still very new at programing and I'm sitting with a mental block as to how I can overcome my issue. Some advice or pointers would be appreciated.

I am trying to build a pilots logbook.
Looking at the aircraft, you are supposed to log the following data for each flight:

1. Type of aircraft
2. If the type is a single- or multi engine aircraft
3. Registration of aircraft.

For instance:

1. Boeing 747
2. Multi engine
3. N1234ABC

All Boeing 747s will of course be classified as multi engine aircraft, but you may fly more than one registation of the type.

Now, using tkinter, and to avoid mistakes, 2 comboboxes for the above (multi/single should be known in background for selected type), how do I connect them?

So first combobox will be 'type' and then the next ('registration') must only show registrations for the specific type.

My idea was something like below:

```py
aircrafts = {

{'Boeing747': ['ME', 'N123ABC', 'N111AAA', 'N462AUF'},

{'type2': [se, reg1, reg2, reg3},

{'type3': [me, reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4}

}
```

When the data gets logged, it can use the first item in the list to find out if it is single/multi engined, to ensure the hours flown gets logged under the correct column.

Am I planning in the right direction, or is there an easier/better way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',func)`, where in `func` you will update the value of the 2nd combobox to change with the first selection.

Answer (score 0):

And I think I have a solution.
Two separate dictionaries.
One for all single engined aircraft, and one for multi engined aircraft.

Then, I can combine the keys of borh in a list for combobox values. By aelecting a value, the dunction can search both dictionaries for it, to find the relevant registrations.

Am I right?